# Apache 2.4.41 tries to bind all interfaces on boot - but works fine if I start by service

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, apache2

The title says it all.
My problem:
I reboot my server and Apache is dead, websites are down.
Seems like Apache is trying to bind on all IPs... but why?

If I check why, by issuing: `service apache2 status`

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-12-15 00:25:19 CET; 18s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/

Dec 15 00:25:19 y systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 15 00:25:19 y apachectl[563]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using [ipv6 addr]. Set the 'ServerN>
Dec 15 00:25:19 y apachectl[563]: (99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 1.2.3.4:80
Dec 15 00:25:19 y apachectl[563]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Dec 15 00:25:19 y apachectl[563]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Dec 15 00:25:19 y apachectl[549]: Action 'start' failed.
Dec 15 00:25:19 y apachectl[549]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Dec 15 00:25:19 y systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 15 00:25:19 y systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 15 00:25:19 y systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

- OS is a bone-stock Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS running on a server.
- The server has two (ipv4) IPs and I want Apache to only bind to 1 ipv4.

`/etc/apache2/ports.conf` contains only this:

```
Listen 1.2.3.4:80
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 1.2.3.4:443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 1.2.3.4:443
</IfModule>
```

Each VirtualHost only contains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
</VirtualHost>
```

And a separate config for SSL (auto-created by Certbot ACME).

Comment: So obviously, the `service apache2 restart` (which works) is different, than the service that gets called on boot. But why?

Comment: Is there anything in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` to better explain the issue? It may also be worth while to look at `/var/log/syslog` to see if Apache is starting before the network interfaces are up, which would certainly cause this sort of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a new bug/issue regarding [Mailcow](https://mailcow.github.io/mailcow-dockerized-docs/), or it's related to networking if you have multiple IPs on the interface. On Ubuntu 18.04, it's Netplan. (So basically I can't pinpoint the culprit for now.)

Anyway. Here is the workaround (kudos to Michael).
In `/etc/sysctl.conf`, add these  lines to the end:

```
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1
net.ipv6.ip_nonlocal_bind=1
```

See [docs](https://sysctl-explorer.net/net/ipv6/ip_nonlocal_bind/).